# jQuery parent selectors

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

Is there a jQuery parent selector that traverses up the DOM until the first match is found?

Eg:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="foo">hello!</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

to find the row from the div I am using:

`$('#foo').parent().parent();`

It feels like I should be able to write something like

`$('#foo').firstParent('tr');`

but I can't find any such function in the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for this:

```
$('#foo').closest('tr');
```

If it helps, there's a category specifically for this to narrow your future searches to: [Tree Traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)

Comment: Thanks and cheers for the tree traversal link. I would never have found that, seems a pretty badly named function imho.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet - When you search the API: http://api.jquery.com/ find a function you know to be in the same area, and on the right it'll have links to the categories it belongs to, that's usually the quickest route :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(element).parents('TR:first');
```

Edit: Or what Nick said below - forgot about that sucker.

Comment: +1 - This is the long-hand equivalent of `.closest('tr')` so certainly a valid approach :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foo').parent('tr')
```

Comment: This doesn't behave like most people expect, it selects the parent *if* it's a `<tr>`, if it's not a `<tr>` you get an empty set.  The selector is a filter, rather than a search term, it's equivalent to `.parent().filter('tr')` for that step :)